# How to sum up registered hours between two dates (Not just total hours between two dates)

Tags: sql-server-2008

I couldn't find questions matching mine. If you know one, please let me know.

I need a select statement that shows me the total hours of absence for an employee between to dates.

Example:

Employee Dennis had absence from 2014-06-10 to 2014-06-13.
This employee had different absence hours between the dates.
Lets say that Dennis have been absent like this:

```
2014-06-10: 477 minutes
2014-06-11: 498 minutes
2014-06-12: 491 minutes
2014-06-13: 397 minutes
total absence: 1863 minutes
```

I want to get an output like this:

I have the tables
**EmployeeTime** that have the hours of absence per day.
**AbsenceDays** that have the from and till date for a absence.

EmployeeTime would look like this:

```
| EmployeeName | Date | RegisteredHour |
```

and AbsenceDays would look like this:

```
| FromDate | TillDate | AbsenceId | KeyNo |
```

I have a third table **LogTable** that can link these two tables together by KeyNo and EmployeeId.

The output I get:

```
| EmployeeName | FromDate   | TillDate   | Days |Days without weekends | Date       | RegisteredHour | Total min absence
| Dennis       | 2014-06-10 | 2014-06-13 | 4    |        4             | 2014-06-10 | 477            | 9540
| Dennis       | 2014-06-10 | 2014-06-13 | 4    |        4             | 2014-06-11 | 498            | 9960
| Dennis       | 2014-06-10 | 2014-06-13 | 4    |        4             | 2014-06-12 | 491            | 9960
| Dennis       | 2014-06-10 | 2014-06-13 | 4    |        4             | 2014-06-13 | 397            | 7940
| Joanne       | 2014-05-09 | 2014-05-12 | 4    |        2             | 2014-05-09 | 420            | 2100
| Joanne       | 2014-05-09 | 2014-05-12 | 4    |        2             | 2014-05-10 | 0              | 0
| Joanne       | 2014-05-09 | 2014-05-12 | 4    |        2             | 2014-05-11 | 0              | 0
| Joanne       | 2014-05-09 | 2014-05-12 | 4    |        2             | 2014-05-12 | 450            | 2250
```

I need to get this result:

```
| EmployeeName | FromDate   | TillDate   | Days |Days without weekends | Total min absence
| Dennis       | 2014-06-10 | 2014-06-13 | 4    |        4             | 1863
| Joanne       | 2014-06-09 | 2014-06-12 | 4    |        2             | 870
```

My code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    EmployeeTime.Name,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),FromDate,20) FromDate,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Tilldate,20) Tilldate,
    (DATEDIFF(DD, FromDate, Tilldate) +1) TotalDays,
    (DATEDIFF(DD, FromDate, Tilldate) +1) - (DATEDIFF(wk, FromDate, Tilldate) * 2) DaysMinusWeekends,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Dato,105) DateDato,
    RegisteredHour,
    SUM(RegisteredHour) Total
FROM EmployeeTime, AbsenceDays, LogTable
WHERE EmployeeTime.EmployeeId = LogTable.EmployeeId
    AND LogTable.KeyNo = AbsenceDays.KeyNo
    AND EmployeeTime.EmployeeId = 'D994'
    AND (DATEDIFF(DD, FromDate, TillDate) +1) = 4
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),FromDate,20) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Dato,20)
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TillDate,20) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Dato,20)
    GROUP BY EmployeeTime.EmployeeId,FromDate, TillDate, Dato, RegisteredHour
    ORDER BY EmployeeTime.EmployeeId
```

Note: I need an answer where you don't self-join tables or use WITH queries; SELECT has to be the first thing in the SQL or the program won't understand it.

Comment: I've tried to make this more readable, but there are some things I don't understand.  It would be helpful if you could show the full definition (`CREATE TABLE ...`) for all of the tables involved.  It would also be helpful if you could clarify what you mean by "I need an answer where you don't join tables" -- the SELECT you show *does* join tables, and your schema looks like this can't be done without a join.

Comment: Thank you I'm back tomorrow so I just made a quick edit!

Answer (score 0):

This is my best guess at an answer.  It probably won't work as-is for you because: (1) I don't know the full table schema for all your tables; (2) I don't understand what you mean by "I need an answer where you don't join tables"; (3) I only know PostgreSQL, not SQL Server.

In English, what you want to do is pick a row of `AbsenceDays` and then use the `FromDate` and `TillDate` to select a set of rows in `EmployeeTime`, and then sum the `RegisteredHour` column in *those* rather than the absolute date difference.  The most obvious way to do that is

```
SELECT et.EmployeeName, ad.FromDate, ad.TillDate, SUM(et.RegisteredHour)

  FROM LogTable lt
  JOIN EmployeeTime et ON lt.EmployeeId = et.EmployeeId
  JOIN AbsenceDays ad  ON lt.KeyNo      = ad.KeyNo

 WHERE et.Date >= ad.FromDate
   AND et.Date <= ad.TillDate
-- AND et.EmployeeName = 'Dennis'

 GROUP BY et.EmployeeName, ad.FromDate, ad.TillDate
 ORDER BY et.EmployeeName, ad.FromDate;
```

Looking back at your code, it seems like you have essentially this embedded in there, but obfuscated with a lot of CONVERTs and DATEDIFFs that seem unnecessary to me.  That may be because, again, I only know PostgreSQL.  I recommend you strip your code down to a bare minimum, like this, and then add conversions back in until the database accepts it.

Another potential problem would be if (EmployeeName, FromDate, TillDate) doesn't uniquely identify one continuous absence.  (You seem to have two ID columns in AbsenceDays; that suggests this might be an issue.)  You also talk inconsistently of minutes and hours, so I don't know which you actually want.  And finally, I have *no idea* how to compute the number of non-weekend days.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

RegisteredHour is minutes in db but in the program at my work they show as hours and minutes.

The conversion-thing I do is because the dates I get is with minutes and the minutes from et.Date isn't quite the same as the minutes from ad.from- and tilldates.
I convert them so I only compare them by yyyy-mm-dd.

I did your example, but the sum of the registered hours do not give sense for me: Tony have three absence days with 450 minutes per day. That should give 1350 but SUM(et.RegisteredHour) gives 3600.

Comment: I don't think I can help you any further with the information you've provided. There must be something strange about the values in RegisteredHour.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and, using that advice, ask a new question.  Also you may have better luck on http://dba.stackexchange.com/