# Is it possible to have a WITH-clause inside a SELECT statement?

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have a cloud-based GUI at my work where I can choose some fields from different tables so it can print out the values afterwards. It is not possible for me to write a WITH clause before a SELECT statement as the program automatically write SELECT first. So I want to know If it is possible somehow.

Comment: There is not enough information here for me to even understand what your question is. What are you trying to achieve and why do you think you need a WITH statement and what is the SELECT statement trying to select and what is your goal here?

Comment: It was a general question, but the question is based on my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29011499/3940497
If I could write it all in a With-clause and could embrace it with a SELECT it would propably work I think.

Comment: I don't believe you can do this. I believe you'll need to use a subquery, inline view, derived table, or whatever you want to call it instead of a CTE.  However, you could wrap the query the way you want to write it in a VIEW, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, according to MSDN documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) :

```
<SELECT statement> ::=  
    [WITH <common_table_expression> [,...n]]
    <query_expression> 
    [ ORDER BY { order_by_expression | column_position [ ASC | DESC ] } 
  [ ,...n ] ] 
    [ <FOR Clause>] 
    [ OPTION ( <query_hint> [ ,...n ] ) ] 
<query_expression> ::= 
    { <query_specification> | ( <query_expression> ) } 
    [  { UNION [ ALL ] | EXCEPT | INTERSECT }
        <query_specification> | ( <query_expression> ) [...n ] ] 
<query_specification> ::= 
SELECT [ ALL | DISTINCT ] 
    [TOP ( expression ) [PERCENT] [ WITH TIES ] ] 
    < select_list > 
    [ INTO new_table ] 
    [ FROM { <table_source> } [ ,...n ] ] 
    [ WHERE <search_condition> ] 
    [ <GROUP BY> ] 
    [ HAVING < search_condition > ]
```

Comment: Thanks, now I got something to try the next few days!

Comment: I don't see where that specification says you can use `[WITH <common_table_expression> [,...n]]` inside or after the `<query_expression>`.

Comment: Yann, I agree with @BaconBits. Can you provide a query that does what you claim? (perhaps you mean something else and we have misunderstood).

Comment: You are both right. But you can use the with outside another query, and place this query in a Select again. Have I misunderstood the question? @zwol has posted a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find any other way around it, this GUI might be persuaded to accept

```
SELECT * FROM (
  -- write your entire select statement here
);
```